# how to use struct in a class

Tags: c++, class, struct

lifeform.h

```
class lifeform
{
  public:
    struct item;
    void buyItem(item &a);
   //code..
};
```

lifeform.cpp

```
struct lifeform::item
{
std::string type,name;
bool own;
int value,feature;

    item(std::string _type,std::string _name,int _value,int _feature):type(_type), name(_name),value(_value),feature(_feature)
     {
        own=false;
     }
};

lifeform::item lBoots("boots","Leather Boots",70,20);

void lifeform::buyItem(item &a)
{
if(a.own==0)
{

    inventory.push_back(a);
    a.own=1;
    addGold(-a.value);
    std::cout << "Added " << a.name << " to the inventory.";

    if(a.type=="boots")
    {
        hp-=inventory[1].feature;
        inventory[1]=a;
        std::cout << " ( HP + " << a.feature << " )\n";
        maxHp+=a.feature;
        hp+=a.feature;
    }
    }
```

there is no error so far but when i wanna use them in main.cpp like this

```
 #include "lifeform.h"
 int main()
 {
 lifeform p;
 p.buyItem(lBoots);
 }
```

compiler says me [Error] 'lBoots' was not declared in this scope but i declared it class am i missing something?

Comment: It may be relevant to share what `IGauntlets` is.

Comment: I don't see any definition of `lGauntlets`. Do you mean `lBoots`? And you need to *declare* is in the header file or no other [translation unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) will know about it.

Comment: @RedPotato remember that `struct` and `class`  really are the same thing in C++. The only difference is that struct default access level is public, so Inheritance and member are by default public, whereas class default level is private. Aside from that, there is no difference.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yeah yeah its `lBoots`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use your `lifeform::item lBoots` you need to declare it in main:

```
#include "lifeform.h"

extern lifeform::item lBoots; // <-- you need this.

int main()
{
    lifeform p;
    p.buyItem(lBoots);
}
```

Or alternatively you should place `extern lifeform::item lBoots;` in your `lifeform.h`.

Comment: The problem with op is not `lifeform::item` to be an incomplete type, but to expose `lBoots` as an extern variable in his header.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot there is no problem with lifeform::item , the problem is i declared `lBoots` in _class.cpp_ but cant use in _main.cpp_

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot yes I see it now, I think the question got edited.

Comment: @RedPotato I updated the answer, you need to declare `lBoots` in main.cpp to be able to reference it.

Comment: @Pavel the declaration of `extern lifeform::item lBoots` belongs in `lifeform.h`. edit that and the upvote is yours.

Comment: @Pavel oh god thank you i didnt know there is such thing as `extern`